# При создание запроса Q, выдает пустой queryset. Django

Tags: python, django

Есть переменная condition, которая формирует запрос. Но при вызове этого запроса, отдает пустой queryset. Запись в базе точно есть, которая должна отфильтроваться. Где ошибка?

**view**

```
for r in v['relateddata']:
   condition &= Q(related_uuid__icontains=r)

print(condition)
>> (AND: ('related_uuid__icontains', 'jLmWQmRN3wJZtHYP6p9f3c'), ('relat
ed_uuid__icontains', 'MbGjdVzaeNgWtfqRC8JXtH'))

test = Money.objects.filter(condition)
print(test)
>> <QuerySet []>
```

Comment: Ну видимо в базе всё-таки нет записи, которая удовлетворяет этим двум условиям **одновременно**

Comment: @andreymal да, оказалось надо использовать |, а не &